# combining list of list to single list Python

Tags: python, list

I am still learning Python and its terminology so perhaps the way I ask my question is wrong. I have some code that produces results like:

```
['S 5.3', 0]   
['S 5.4', 10]    
['S 5.5', 20]
```

With this I assume this is a list of lists. How can I combine them to have one single list like:

```
[['S 5.3', 0], ['S 5.4', 10], ['S 5.5', 20]]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you want to put these list  in a list? Or try to use a dict?

Comment: Is that your some code returns above list one by one ? Because that can't be single output ?

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the Python code that produces this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into `append` and `extend` methods

The following [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) shows the usage of append() method.

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc'];
aList.append( 2009 );
print "Updated List : ", aList
When we run above program, it produces following result −

Updated List :  [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 2009]
```

The following [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) shows the usage of extend() method.

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 123];
bList = [2009, 'manni'];
aList.extend(bList)

print "Extended List : ", aList 
When we run above program, it produces following result −

Extended List :  [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 123, 2009, 'manni']
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). This is just an example (I'll let you learn, through the documentation, how to use, for example, the `append` method in this scenario):

Code:

```
list1 = ['S 5.3', 0]   
list2 = ['S 5.4', 10]    
list3 = ['S 5.5', 20]  

nested_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
print(nested_lists)
```

Output:

```
[['S 5.3', 0],['S 5.4', 10],['S 5.5', 20]]
```

Comment: that works well when you have each list as a variable. what about in the case where each list represents a record

Comment: How so? What do you mean by "record"?

Comment: I figured it out. Meant like sql style output where a query returns row of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
look into itertools module
```

[chain](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import  chain

list1 = ['S 5.3', 0]
list2 = ['S 5.4', 10]
list3 = ['S 5.5', 20]

result = chain(list1, list2, list3)

print(list(result))

['S 5.3', 0, 'S 5.4', 10, 'S 5.5', 20]
```